# Android: Update the SQLiteOpenHelper's context property after device rotation

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, rotation, android-asynctask

I'm trying to put some time-consumed database operations into the background thread with the help of `AsyncTask`. In order to handle the possible device rotation, I save my `AsyncTask` instance in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and reuse them in `onCreate()`. So far so good...

However since the Activity is recreated after device rotation, I must update all `Activity` references in my `AsyncTask` to the new created one. The problem is that, the `SQLiteOpenHelper` inside the `AsyncTask` also has a context instance which is passed through its constructor and I just passed the old `Activity` instance before, now how can I update it to the new `Activity`?

I have tested, It seems work even I don't update the context of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. But I'm still not sure if it is OK.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leaking an `Activity` instance when you do this, since the garbage collector cannot free it up.  Depending on your app, this may or may not be fatal to your memory usage, but it's not good in any case.

You should either use the application `Context` for your database or create a `ContentProvider` which has its own context to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use the application context (`getApplicationContext()`) instead of the activity one (`this`). If you use the activity context you leak that

Answer (score 0):

I found an impressiv article about context and memory leak:
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html